# I get empty string when trying to access a field inside a method in C++

Tags: c++, class, methods, field

Following are my files:

student.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>      // time()
#include <cstdlib>    // srand(), rand()
#include <algorithm>  // min_element(), max_element(), sort()

/**
 * Class student for holding a single student's record.
 */
class Student
{
// These will not be accessible from else where
private:
  // Holds the name of the student.
  std::string name_;
  // Roll no. of the student.
  int number_;
  // A vector to hold grades.
  std::vector<int> grades_;
  // Number of courses taken by the student.
  const int num_courses_;
  // Alphabets.
  char alpha[63] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
  // Returns a random number
  int rand_gen(int min, int max);

  // Generates a random name.
  std::string gen_name();
  // Generates a random roll number.
  int gen_number();
  // Generates a grade.
  int gen_grade();


public:
  // Constructor function that initiates with name and
  // number of a student.
  Student();
  // << operator overloading.
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(
    std::ostream& os, const Student& s);
  // Prints grades of a student.
  void print_grades(std::ostream& os) const;
  // Prints the average.
  double compute_average();
};

/** CONSTRUCTOR **/
Student::Student() :
  name_(gen_name()), number_(gen_number()), num_courses_(5)
{
  gen_grade();
}

/** Overloading '<<' operator **/
std::ostream& operator<<(
  std::ostream& os, const Student& s)
{
  os << "Name = " << s.name_
     << ", Number = " << s.number_;
  return os;
}

/** Print Grades **/
void Student::print_grades(std::ostream& os) const
{
  for (int i = 0; i < num_courses_; ++i) {
    os << grades_[i] << ", ";
  }
}

/** Generates random numbers between min and max **/
int Student::rand_gen(int min, int max) {
  return std::rand()%(max - min + 1) + min;
}

double Student::compute_average()
{
  int sum = 0;
  // Assuming no one will manipulate number of courses
  for (int g : grades_)
    sum += g;
  // Change this to return sum / grades_.size(); incase you are going serious.
  return sum / 5;
}


// Generates a random name.
std::string Student::gen_name()
{
  // This results in empty string printing.
  std::cout << this->alpha << std::endl;
  int size = this->rand_gen(6, 12);
  std::string rand_name = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    rand_name += this->alpha[this->rand_gen(0, 61)];
    std::cout << rand_name;
  }
  return rand_name;
}

// Generates a roll number for students.
int Student::gen_number()
{
  // Produce a random number between 201100000
  // and 201600000
  return this->rand_gen(201100000, 201600000);
}

// Generates a Grade.
int Student::gen_grade()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < num_courses_; ++i) {
    // Generate some random number and push it into grades vector.
    grades_.push_back(this->rand_gen(70, 100));
  }
}
```

and my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.cpp"
#include <ctime>      // time()
#include <cstdlib>    // srand(), rand()
#include <algorithm>  // min_element(), max_element(), sort()

int main()
{
  Student *s1 = new Student();
  std::cout << *s1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << s1->compute_average() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I run my main.cpp All i get is

```
// I have an empty line on terminal here
Name = , Number = 201115456
88
```

Actually the get_name() method should output a name, but it is not able to access the alpha char array. I have tried cout - ing the char from inside the get_name(), that's what causes the emty line in the output.
Which is not what I expect. Please help. FYI I am total novice, I know I over coded without emphasis on basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shortest words - initialization order.
In constructor, when you start initialization of `name_`, you call `gen_name()` which uses `alpha`, which... has not been initialized yet. The order of initialization of members is the same, as order of declaration.
Shortest solution - move declaration of:

```
// Alphabets.
char alpha[63] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
```

at the beginning of your members list (at least before `name_` declaration).

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, I undeleted this question just to get you an upvote. Before I know whats happening there is like a barrage of downvotes on my question, because I wasn't brainy enough to ask right kind of questions.

Comment: Your solution worked right away, but I still am not clear about the concept. How is it that alpha is not initiated? Can you be more descriptive?

Comment: So its like the compiler hits the members when it needs a particular variable?

Comment: Constructor initializes members in the same order as they are declared (in class). You are trying to initialize `name_` field using `gen_name()` method. Your implementation of the method uses `alpha` field, which is declared after (and will be also initialized with "abcd..." later then) `name_` field. So in the moment of `name_` initialization (`gen_name()` invocation), field `alpha` is declared - you can access its value - but has not been initialized (with "abc...") yet, so it contains "random" data (which can be empty string).

Comment: Okay got it thanks a lot!, so the constructor stuff happens before the variable initialization. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Modified constructor

```
    /** CONSTRUCTOR **/
   Student::Student() :
   number_(gen_number()), num_courses_(5)
  {
         std::string str =       
       "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
         strncpy_s(alpha, str.c_str(), sizeof(alpha));

        name_ = gen_name();
        gen_grade();
    }
```

and also change alpha definition to declaration : **char alpha[63];**

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering bro